# 17 pixels added to element.clientWidth and element.clientHeight

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, width

I'm making an equation plotter and when I get clientWidth to make the graph cover the screen, it gives real width+17 px, same with the height, See output in the console.

but when I run the same console.log at the end of code, it outputs the real width (see code and screenshot)

[image]

relevant code:

```js
var paper = document.getElementsByClassName("paper")[0];
paper.innerHTML = "";
var width = paper.clientWidth;
var height = paper.clientHeight;
console.log(width, height); //THIS IS THE ONE WITH EXTRA 17 PIXELS
var paper_svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
paper_svg.setAttribute("width", width);
paper_svg.setAttribute("height", height);
paper.appendChild(paper_svg);
//grid
function makeGrid(xi, xf, yi, yf) {
  //find the point on the x axis that is closest to 0
  var x0 = Math.round((0 - xi) / (xf - xi) * width);
  //make the x axis
  var xaxis = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");
  xaxis.setAttribute("x1", 0);
  xaxis.setAttribute("y1", y0);
  xaxis.setAttribute("x2", width);
  xaxis.setAttribute("y2", y0);
  xaxis.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
  xaxis.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
  paper_svg.appendChild(xaxis);
};
makeGrid(-10, 10, -5, 5);
////////////
console.log(paper.clientWidth, paper.clientHeight) //OUTPUTS THE REAL WIDTH AND HEIGHT OF THE PAPER
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.paper {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.controls #eq-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="eq-input" placeholder="Equation" value="sin(x)">
    <input type="range" id="n-val" min="10" max="10000" value="5000">
  </div>
  <div class="paper">
    <!-- PAPER IS THE PLACE WHERE WE DRAW THE GRAPHS -->
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Make your <svg> element `display:block`.

Comment: 17px feels like a scrollbar Issue. If you can - try slapping some overflow:hidden on your .paper

Comment: well, overflow: hidden did fix the problem, by hiding the extra part, but I'm still tryna figure out what was wrong.